# How to make mousedown event to prevent single click effect and only affect click being held

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i had to use mousedown instead of using the draggable start, drag events because of the jQuery snapping... 
The jQuery UI Support gave me this solution which works, but if you click on the red block, a single click... you can see that the black guides appear even though I don't like that.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/cLs7mq4p/2/) that jQuery UI Team fixed for my question.

Is there any way to make it work so that the single click doesn't show up the black lines only when holding the click?

Here's the simple code:

```
$(".block").draggable({
    snap: ".guide",
    snapTolerance: 10,
    stop: function( event, ui) {
        $(".h-line").css("display", "none");
    }
}).on( "mousedown", function(event) {
    $(".h-line").css("display", "block");
});
```

Maybe by setting a setTimeout? but is that the proper solution?

Comment: possibly you need use `.on( "mouseup"...` event instead of `stop`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cLs7mq4p/3/)

Comment: Yea but click over the red block, see that it shows the lines and then dissapears? i don't want that to happen, and when i tried using setInterval, the snapTolerance doesn't work again with it.

Comment: Yea, actually the guy in jQuery UI Support did the mouseup thing, but still the click is being taken into consideration.

Comment: so as quick fix you can use also `mousemove` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cLs7mq4p/4/)

Comment: damn you are a genius! :) thanks Grundy! if you want, put it as an answer and i will tick it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you simple click on '.block' you show '.h-line' on _mousedown, but not raise *dragstart*, so and *dragstop* don't raise.
for quick fix you can use *mousemove* and *mouseup* events like this

```
$(".block").draggable({
    snap: ".guide",
    snapTolerance: 10
}).on( "mousedown", function() {
    this.t = true;
}).on( "mouseup",function(){
    this.t = false;
    $(".h-line").css("display", "none");
}).on("mousemove", function(){
    if(this.t && $(".h-line:visible").length === 0)
        $(".h-line").css("display", "block");
});
```

[sample on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLs7mq4p/5/)